# Why am I getting singleton cant be dumped err?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to add a variable value into session, I am getting `singleton cant be dumped` err.

Here is the value in the varibale

```
[
    [0] {
                                        :id => "574ecb43a7a5bb44c000443b",
                                       :_id => "574ecb43a7a5bb44c000443b",
                                    :active => true,
                              :capabilities => {
            :network_connections => [
                [0] {
                    :type => "ethernet-wan",
                    :name => "wan"
                },
                [1] {
                    :type => "ethernet-lan",
                    :name => "lan"
                },
                [2] {
                    :type => "wifi",
                    :name => "wlan"
                },
                [3] {
                    :type => "cellular",
                    :name => "wwan"
                }
            ]
        },
                             :commander_ids => [],
                                :created_at => "2016-05-11T15:46:12+00:00",
                                :deleted_at => nil,
                       :firmware_upgradable => true,
                              :ingestor_ids => [],
                :last_known_translator_port => nil,
                          :long_description => "this is a liong desc",
                              :manufacturer => "test_sushant",
                                     :model => "sushant_test",
                                      :name => "zxc",
        :parent_gateway_data_source_type_id => nil,
                                  :rule_ids => [],
                                  :software => "qwe",
                                :translator => "edge",
                                      :type => "asd",
                                :updated_at => "2016-05-11T15:46:12+00:00",
                                   :user_id => "572adee5a7a5bb320b000852"
    },
```

The variable is an array of objects. I do not know why this is causing an err.

Comment: Can you include the code that is generating this error?

Comment: @SomeGuy , `session[:test] = @that_var` This is how i have assigned the value into session and it gives me the err.